# VS2013 Gridview issue

Tags: gridview, visual-studio-2013

I am having an issue with the Gridview control in VS2013.  I have a simple page with a Gridview that loads 200 records. I need to be able to edit the First & Last Name so they are in TemplateFields. When I open the page in IE11 the page displays the records in the Gridview fine but the page is mostly unresponsive for several minutes. If I try to scroll down the scroll bars just sit there for a good 10 seconds and then they move a little.  If there are other links on the page they don't work and even closing the web browser takes a while.  I have tried this in Firefox and Chrome and have the same issue although not as pronounced. I created the exact same project in VS2010 and the page with the exact same code works fine. Does anyone know why this is happening.

html Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>    
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
Public Class WebForm1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub LoadGrid()

    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim dr As DataRow

    dt = New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("LastName", GetType(String))

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For i = 0 To 200
        dr = dt.NewRow
        dr(0) = i
        dr(1) = "John" & i.ToString
        dr(2) = "Doe" & i.ToString

        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next

    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found an answer to this issue but have narrowed it down a little further.  If I have an 'ID' attribute in the controls in the ItemTemplate then the page is very slow when first loaded.  If I remove the 'ID' attribute from the textbox and labels in the ItemTemplate then the page loads and works fine.  Why would having an 'ID' attribute cause the page to be so slow when it is first loaded??